# Write a boolean in PHP like VB6

Tags: php, vb6

a convert a VB6 code into PHP. But I have a problem:
in VB6:

```
    Open myFile For Binary Access Write As numFile
      Put #numFile, , True
      '(...)
    close numFile
```

this file is : ÿÿ

But I try to do this in PHP :

```
    $fp = fopen("test","wb");
    $fwrite = fwrite($fp, TRUE);
    fclose($fp);
```

I mean that a boolean in VB6 is like an integer.
I have try all format of pack() but no issu (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

```
    $fwrite  = fwrite($fp, pack('S', TRUE));
```

an idea ?

Comment: What does ÿÿ have to do with an integer? And what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: how many `True`s have you written to that file in VB6?

Comment: (I do write a binary file like a old software). For my test I have only Put a boolean TRUE  et in Notepad++ TRUE=ÿÿ

Comment: and when I write FALSE in VB6, I have two NUL char

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your file to be readable by VB6 as a file of booleans, you will have to write each boolean `true` as `"\xFF\xFF"` and each boolean `false` as `"\x00\x00"`. I don't think that `pack()` can help you in doing so. E.g.:

```
fwrite($fp, $my_boolean ? "\xFF\xFF" : "\x00\x00");
```

`ÿ` is the ISO-8859-1 / Windows codepage 1252 value of `255`

Comment: you are welcome. BTW, VB6 uses 16 bits to store 1 bit of information, it seems...